# All time based triggers seem to run at the same time

Tags: google-sheets

I have multiple time based triggers in a google sheet (most of which are supposed to run every 15 minutes and one of which is supposed to run once a day). These scripts that the triggers run simply generate random numbers in specific cells (one per each script/trigger). These cells changing then triggers a script that pulls from an API. The issue is that I can only pull so much from the site's API before it locks me out (60/pulls per minute is the limit). The scripts seems to all run at the same time on occasion (including the one thats supposed to only run once a day) which results in me being locked out of the API and receiving no data. Does anyone know why everything would be running at the same time? This happens when the once a day trigger shouldn't be active too.

Comment: I'd suggest you a different strategy. 
1. Use LockService to prevent the script portion that calls the API to run in parallel
2. When you get the Http 429 (or other response from your API that indicates that the limit has been reached), create a one-off time trigger/callback to continue running your script in 1 minute
Do not forget to delete the trigger after it has been run

Answer (score 0):

For this use case you might be better off chaining your functions.
So you would only schedule `functionA()`, and at the end of it you call `functionB()`, and so on.
That also allow you to put a Sleep() function between them if your API requires it.
If every function are in the same project that's straightforward, but if they are in different project you will need to publish your projects as libraries.
It's not pretty but it will do the tricky.

Comment: I'm kind of new to the whole scripting thing so I'm not sure what this should look like. I tried the following `SpreadsheetApp.openById('1cMDWkDPZmDGBHTXBCoUsybH0h3lf6ND-VJSoh8Df09k').getRange('bazaar prices!a1').setValue(Math.random());
  Utilities.sleep(60000);` and copy and pasted that into the same function for each different cell I wanted to change (functions all do the same thing, just to different cells). Any more help would be appreciated.